# composing a double exposure in the LCD

Tags: multiple-exposure

I am interested in creating digital double exposure images, but sometimes my subjects aren't exactly lined up the way I want them to be.

Is there a camera that has a feature, or an after-market modification such as magic lantern, that would allow you to compose a double exposure in the LCD viewfinder?

What I am thinking is that there could be a feature where you could select a previously shot image to display, semi-transparently, over the current image in the viewfinder. That way, you could line up exactly the two images for creating the double exposure afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, there's not a whole lot of love for double exposure in camera. It can easily be accomplished in post-processing, with finer control over exposure blending, masking out areas, etc. The only reason I can think of to perform it in camera is if there were restrictions against post-processing when you submit images (to publishers such as Nation Geographic, or for contests with no-post-processing rules).

> Is there a camera that has a feature, or an after-market modification such as magic lantern, that would allow you to compose a double exposure in the LCD viewfinder?

Several Canon DSLRs have that feature (showing the image on the LCD display, since they do not have LCD viewfinders). For instance, [in this popular YouTube video](https://youtu.be/Lcu8SdcsYnY), Sara Byrne describes how to create double exposures with the 5D Mark III, and specifically mentions using Live View with the first image overlaid to help the framing.

Nikons do not have this feature. In fact, you cannot shoot multiple exposures while in Live View with Nikons.

With regard to MagicLantern, it appears [this feature has been closed as "WONTFIX"](http://www.magiclantern.fm/forum/index.php?topic=5622.msg39280#msg39280) (i.e., it will not be implemented) (at least as of May 2013). Generally, the mentality at MagicLantern is that they won't implement features that can be accomplished in post-processing.